# how to do that can click the show content part?

Tags: javascript, css

http://phplist.xxmn.com/menu.html

When the mouse hover on the navigation (`cpanel`). it shows the  corresponding content under it. but i can't click the link in it. is there a way to get it.i know it will be using setTimeout. but i don't know how to do. thank you.

when i change the `top` value small.but under IE7 and IE6.i still can't click the link in the showing content.

Comment: You don't have only to use setTimeout but to check if you're over the menu you opened. I suggest you look at existing menu code (google) as it is something that is hard to do right without experience.

Comment: Can you post some sample code? That way if your site gets fixed this question will still be useful to future users.

Answer (score 1):

not good way but work for you, better way : use css `top = 20px`:

```
var timeout;

$(function(){ // = document.ready
    $("#nav ul li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, function() {

        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).find(".sub-menu").hide();
        },1000); // 1000 = 1 second
    });
});
```

Comment: it's ok. but when i leave out the content. the show content can't hide. it must be wait 1 second. is there a way to avoid it. thank you

Comment: @run no, you must change you menu structure or only remove space bettween then, if you set top 20, problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You should put the content div closer, better yet next to the menu element and change how it appears and disappears. On menu `mouseover` you show it and on content `mouseout` you hide it. I think this would be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#nav ul li").on('mouseenter', function () {
        $('#nav ul li').find(".sub-menu").hide();
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();
    });

    $('.sub-menu').on('mouseleave click', function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```